# ASP.Net MVC 5 how to use Authorize Attribute with multiple login (Multiple user table)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 5. In the project I'm developing I have two user tables: one for clients and one for employees. I need to create two distinct login forms: one for clients and one for employees. The clients will have access to a particular part of the website, the employees will have access to another distinct part. Each part has its own actions. How can use the Authorize Attribute in order to distringuish clients from employees?

Comment: Best is you can use same table with one `user_role columns` instead of multiple user  table.

Comment: Use the same table but different roles, like in TheAkhemist answer.

Comment: Both employees and clients are users and they should not be treated differently with regards to authorization and authentication. They should be assigned roles that govern the limits of authorization. The AuthorizeAttribute handles roles already, so you'd be much better off taking this approach rather than creating a near-duplicate table to delineate different roles..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About creating different login forms, that won't be necessary at all. You can use one login form for both roles but depending on what you want either to see when logged in, you make use of `User.IsInRole` to verify and maybe redirect them or some other course action of your choice.

This is of course in addition to the answer provided by "The Akhemist".

Comment: This is the most correct way, at the beginning I didn't know if I could change the structure of the database. Then, when I realized I needed to use ASP.NET Identity, I was forced to use a single table for all users and that's the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the roles attribute for different types of users.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Users")]
public class UserController: Controller
{
}

[Authorise(Roles="Employees")]
public class EmployeeController: Controller
{
}


[Authorize(Roles = "User,Customer")]
public ActionResult RoleType()
{                        
    return View();
}

public class MyController : Controller
{
    private const string UserRole = "User";
    private const string EmployeeRole = "Employee";

    [Authorize(Roles = UserRole + "," + EmployeeRole)]
    public ActionResult UserOrEmployee()
    {                        
        return View();
    }
}
```

Only users that have that role now can access the controllers. E.g.the employees controller can only be accessed by users whos role is of type "Employees" and the user controller can only be accessed by users of type role "User".